# mysql update table multiple fields in single command

Tags: python, mysql

Looking for help on updating mysql table mutiple fileds. Am running the following command and getting error. Can anyone help me on this. am updating the table from the value of a dictionary. See the following code

```
cols = change_dict.keys()
vals = change_dict.values()
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "0.0.0.0",user="test",passwd="test",db='maint')
x = conn.cursor()
sql = "update details set %s = '%s' where maint_id=%s" % ( ",".join(cols), ",".join((vals)),id)
print sql
x.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: -1 Not clear. What error are you getting and where? What is the contents of `change_dict`? What query does it come up with (you *have* gone through the trouble of `print`ing it after all)?

Comment: Didn't you ask this earlier? The syntax for setting multiple columns is `update table set col1 = val1, col2 = val2, col3 = val3, ... where ...`

Comment: This might help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: @AshwinMukhija Please don't refer people to w3fools

Comment: There you go. Fixed the bad.

Comment: i know how to update the table. But the question is how will update multiple fileds in single command. Also u can see the above code in which fileds are taking from python dictionary. i dont want to take one by one and do an update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement

```py
sql="UPDATE table name SET field=%s WHERE maint_id=%s", (var1, maint_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
update table set column1 = value1, column2 = value2, column3 = value3 where Condition
```

Comment: That's not much of an answer, he needs to know how to construct that query from the dictionary.

Comment: Yes thats what i am looking for,

Comment: can you paste the correct answer here ?